# Laravel Nova Action Log Table - Actionable - Prevent Auto Update

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

When you use Actionable on the model you get an Actions table at the bottom of a resource.  It is possible to disable this from auto refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

- Make a resource in `app/Nova` directory with name `ActionResource.php`:

```php
<?php


namespace App\Nova;


class ActionResource extends \Laravel\Nova\Actions\ActionResource
{
    public static $polling=false;
    
}
```

- In `config/nova.php` edit option `actions` with newly created resource:

```php
// config/nova.php
...
    'actions' => [
        'resource' => \App\Nova\ActionResource::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Since $polling is a public variable, you can change value from Nova Service Provider class in boot method as follow.

```
\Laravel\Nova\Actions\ActionResource::$polling = false;
```

Similarly for delaying auto refresh on notification

```
Nova::notificationPollingInterval(700);
```